# What does the second parameter of key lambda mean in the sort function in python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

To sort `d` in a descendant order according to the length of each word, we have these implementations in python:

```
d = ["ba","ab","a","b"]

d.sort(key = lambda s: (-len(s), s)) # ['ab', 'ba', 'a', 'b']

d.sort(key = lambda s: -len(s)) # ['ba', 'ab', 'a', 'b']

d.sort(key = lambda s: len(s), reverse = True) # ['ba', 'ab', 'a', 'b']
```

Here is my question:

1. Why is the first result different from the other two?
2. What does the second parameter, `s`, mean, in the lambda function of the first sort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, the sort priorities are based on the elements in the 2-tuple, with the first element in the tuple having the higher priority.

The second element in your toy code acts as a tie-breaker as in the case where the lengths of `ab` and `ba` are tied at a value 2. For any two items in the container, the second element is only compared if the first sort criterion leads to a tie.

Additionally, if ties exist or are not broken (with the second element or generally as with the other two examples), the items are prioritised in their original order; [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is stable.

Also of note, the 2-tuple sort performs a numerical sort on the first tuple item and a lexicographical one on the second.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it mean I could have multiple tie breakers(more than two) if I want?

Comment: @Chang Yes, you certainly can.